# php subdomain session sharing not working properly

Tags: php, session, subdomain

The site configuration is as follows:

testsite.co.kr :  default site

login.testsite.co.kr : subdomain created for integrated login

100.testsite.co.kr : subdomain

200.testsite.co.kr  : subdomain

session_test.php : content start ===========================

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_name("mysession");
session_cache_limiter("no-cache, must-revalidate");
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".testsite.co.kr");
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = "kim";
```

session_test.php  : content end ===========================

After placing and running session_test.php on the **testsite.co.kr** site
,  access to 100.testsite.co.kr or 200.testsite.co.kr, **be logged in**  (can read $_SESSION['userid'])

After placing and running session_test.php on the **login.testsite.co.kr** site
, access to 100.testsite.co.kr or 200.testsite.co.kr, **not be logged in**. (Cannot read $_SESSION['userid'])

Even when logging in at login.testsite.co.kr, is it not possible to log in to another subdomain (session sharing)?

How to log in to login.testsite.co.kr(subdomain) and be logged in state  when accessing another subdomain?

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Note ** The OP is using PHP4.3 which is 13 years old and cannot satisfy modern browser requirements for cookie security.

Add the domain to your session_set_cookie_params in line 1

```
 session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.testsite.co.kr');
```

The params must be set before initializing the session.

This is all covered in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). It also says to keep the leading "." in the domain to allow subdomains to use the cookie.

Comment: thanks but not working yet

Comment: thanks, I tried what you said but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Run ```var_dump(session_get_cookie_params())``` right before starting your session to see what the parameters are for your session.

Comment: thanks,  is checked as follows     array(4) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(14) ".testsite.co.kr" ["secure"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: Using the dev tools in your browser, check the network request to see if any error messages appear in the console. Also, add ```echo ini_get("session.cookie_samesite")``` to your script to see if you have any restrictions on cross-site cookies with the browser. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using chrome, no error message in dev console.   when  echo ini_get("session.cookie_samesite")  , Nothing is output.

Comment: Try setting the samesite session param to "lax". Browsers have been changing their behavior regarding how they handle non-specified samesite settings . What version of php are you using?

Comment: thanks, I tried to set samesite what you said   but it still doesn't work.   my php version  4.3.11

Comment: Wow. PHP4's last release was 13yrs ago. samesite did not exist back then. You need to upgrade to a more current version of PHP.